# How to reference other files when creating new column?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a column in each file that says Client : ABC. The "ABC" is an internal acronym we have for each client. I uploaded a file called acronym and made the following code.

```
for(i in seq_along(filePaths)){
data = within(data, {
subsidiary="Client : acronym[i]"
})
}
```

There were some other functions of my code (that I won't replicate here) that worked fine. But when I wrote the file, I got Client : acronym[i] instead of Client : ABC. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `subsidiary = paste("Client :", acronym[i])`

Comment: That ended up making it look like this: Client :  c(2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 5, 8, 7, 10, 15, 23, 22, 16, 14, 11, 25, 24, 17, 12, 9, 20, 21, 18, 19, 13, 27, 26, 29, 28, 31, 33, 32, 34, 38, 37, 30, 35, 36, 39, 40, 41, 44, 42, 45, 43, 50, 47, 58, 51, 46, 49, 48, 52, 53, 54, 55, 61, 56, 57, 59, 60, 64, 63, 62, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71)

Comment: BTW the acronym file is just 72 rows of acronyms, 1 column wide. I also just added a header but there wasn't run when I ran the code (and I read it head=TRUE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that the way you read in the acronym file resulted in a dataframe, but you are not indexing the dataframe correctly. I can't tell if you want a uniform column with a single client, or a lookup table kind of thing with a unique client. If it is the former, perhaps the example below could help. If it is a sort of lookup table, look into a merge command.

```
acronyms <- read.csv(acronymFile.csv)

for(i in seq_along(filePaths)){
    data <- read.csv(filePaths[i])
    acronym <- acronyms[i,1]
    data$subsidiary = paste("Client :", acronym[i])
}
```

Notice how I indexed the first (and only) column of the acronym dataframe.

Comment: I'll have to run the code in the morning but this looks like it could work. Thanks!

Comment: Better would be to make sure `acronyms` is a vector *before* the loop. Something like `acronyms = unlist(acronyms)`, or `acronyms = acronyms[, 1]` will be much more efficient.